# Slow down enemy movement

Tags: java, performance, game-engine, slick2d

I'm making a game using slick2d - and ive created a pathfinding algorithm, that will allow a 'zombie' to find the shortest path to the main hero.

```
  public void findPrey(int characterXPosition,int characterYPosition){

    Pathfinder p = new Pathfinder();
    n =  p.aStar(xPosition,yPosition,characterXPosition,characterYPosition);
    //n is a linked list which holds node objects in the path
    if(!n.isEmpty()){
        xPosition = (n.get(0).x);
        yPosition = (n.get(0).y);   
    }   
}
```

At the moment this works, but it just moves the zombie a tile (32x32) really quickly - like way too quickly!

I tried this instead:

```
        if(xPosition > n.get(0).x){
            xPosition -= .1f * delta;

        }
        else if(xPosition < n.get(0).x){
            xPosition += .1f * delta;

        }
        if(yPosition < n.get(0).y){
            yPosition += .1f * delta;

        }
        else if(yPosition > n.get(0).y){
            yPosition -= .1f * delta;

        }
```

Which only works if the zombie goes up or left - even then its really jumpy and if its meant to go down or right it goes mental and just keeps going up out of the screen.

So anyone any idea how I can either slow down the movement of the first technique - or know why the second one isnt working?
Thanks for any help!

EDIT - ANSWER

Okay figured a solution out - was pretty basic , I think just staring at the same code for a few hours did me.

In the render method of my 'world' class where the zombies were getting rendered I just put this change in:

```
    Iterator<Zombie> i = zombies.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Zombie z = i.next();

        if (!z.isDead()) {      
            z.updateDelta(newDelta);
            z.incrementCounter(); //put a counter variable in
            if(z.getCounter() % 40 == 0){
                z.findPrey((int)shiftX,(int)shiftY);
            }

            z.render(gc, sbg, g);
        }else{
            i.remove();
        }
    }
```

So i basically just added a counter variable in the Zombie class and then used modular so that it wouldnt get called as frequently.
Thanks for everyone for trying to help.

Comment: if...elseif seems to be redundant - i would minimize it to if..else, if...else. Also, you aren't doing nothing when xPosition is equals to n.get(0).x, same thing for y axis.

Comment: I don't know how your program is implemented, but in the path returned you shouldnt update the position, and then delete that element? instead of using `n.get(0)`, use `n.removeFirst()`. Mmmm, one question, you are calling `findPrey` each step?

Comment: @Christian: I'm afraid the OP searches for the shortest path every update cycle.

Comment: Yes, I just noted it. And I just can't see the problem.

Comment: Yes, its being updated everytime from the render method in my 'world' class - I need it to be if else if because I dont want the zombie to move if the coordinates are the same - I just want it to stay still.

Comment: Does anyone know how to slow down the first technique? that is move it by tiles?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use timers. Then on every computer game will work with the same speed and the movement of your units will be with fixed time.

Units move too fast, because every loop unit is moved. Amount fo loops should be less or decrease the distance moved by units.

Comment: Okay thanks - I'll try this! I did try with threads but it really slowed the program down.

Comment: hmmm I cant seem to get this to work - it just delays it initally - for whatever interval - and then just goes really quickly afterwards.

Comment: The delay should be at the end reversly proportional to taken time in calculations and showing graphics.